# Can't call a message box in PyQt5 as a result of an if statement

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using Python 3 and PyQt5. I'm using QFileDialog.getOpenFileName to open different files into my program, but no more than 4, and I want to display a warning message box if you try to open another file, but can't seem to do it.

```
import pandas
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QAction, QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480))
        self.setWindowTitle("'File' test")
        self.count = 0
        self.datasets = []
        
        openFile = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open documents')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.openCall)
        
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
        
    def openCall(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select one file to open", "C:\PROG\FIN", "CSV files (*.csv)", options=options)
        if files:
            if self.count < 4:
                self.datasets.append(files)
                self.count += 1
                print(self.datasets)
                print(self.count)
            else:
                # The message box should go here
```

Comment: "but can't seem to do it" -> what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
QMessageBox.warning(self, "Title", "Description")
```